# Email On Hold? options

Tags: contacts, email

It looks like there are two options for indicating that an email address in on hold.  Is there a way to add another option?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the use case you are dealing with?

Comment: The current idea is to use the On Hold? option to help mitigate against unwanted emails going out in light of the upcoming due date for GDPR.  I want to make sure that email comms do not go out to contacts who have not opted in for various newsletters.  Yes, there is a chance that we could use the recent extension, [link](https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr) but I want to make extra certain that various staff around the world don't inadvertently communicate with these contacts because they don't know about GDPR.  I'd like to keep the opt-in/out information separate from the normal opt-out.

Comment: So you are thinking of an "On Hold - not opted-in" type option? TBH I have no idea how you would address that.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of an option similar to that. Do you have any other ideas on how I could prohibit any emails going to a contact short of deleting the email address?

Comment: Use the Do Not Email option in Comm Preferences?

Comment: Yes, that would accomplish the same purposes in preventing communication but I'm also wanting to keep track of the date in which a contact communicates this preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record the person indicating their opting-in or opting-out then you could consider using an Activity for this purpose.